# Check word length not working

Tags: javascript, html

### HTML

```
<form name="f1" action="feedback1.php" method="Post" onSubmit="return isDataFilled();" >
    <table border="0" align="center" width="500px" style="max-width: 500px;" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" align="center">
        <tr align="left">
            <td width="25%">
                Enter your subject            </td>
            <td width="75%"><input type="text" name="subject" size="30" value="Your subject" onClick="if(this.value=='Your subject'){this.value=''}; this.style.backgroundColor='#CCFF99'" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your subject'}; this.style.backgroundColor='white'"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
            <td>
                Enter your email<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>            </td>
            <td>        
                <input type="text" name="email" size="30" value="example@mail.com" onClick="if(this.value=='example@mail.com'){this.value=''}; this.style.backgroundColor='#CCFF99'" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='example@mail.com'}; this.style.backgroundColor='white'"/>            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
            <td colspan="2">
                Enter your message here<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>:            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
            <td colspan="2">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="message" title="Your message goes here" onClick= "if(this.value=='Your message goes here'){this.value=''}; this.style.backgroundColor='#CCFF99'" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your message goes here'}; this.style.backgroundColor='white'" >Your message goes here</textarea>            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="" align="right">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="b1" title="Send your message"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">          
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" title="Removes your form data and fill it again"/>            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form
```

### JavaScript

```
function isDataFilled()
{  
    if(document.forms['f1']['email'].value=='example@mail.com')
    {
        alert("No email address in email field!");
        return false;
    }
    if(document.forms['f1']['message'].value=='Your message goes here')
    {
        alert("No message in message field!");
        return false;
    }
    return isEmailCorrect(document.forms["f1"]["email"].value);
    return check_word_length(document.forms['f1']['message'].value, 20);
}

function isEmailCorrect(f_email)
{
    var x=f_email;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
    }
}
function check_word_length(text, over_size)
{
    var word=0;
    var message=text;
    for(i=0;i<message.length;i++)
    {
        if(message.charAt(i)==" ")
        {
            word=0;            
        }
        else
        {
            word++;
            if(word>=over_size)
            {
                alert("Too long text entered");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function `check_word_length(text, over_size)` is not working. I'm confused because I think my code is alright.

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: DOn't use inline event handlers. At least move them into a function that you call. Binding a single handler to multiple elements from javascript (or delegating) would be even better. Also, your table does not look very tabular. Instead, you could use a bunch of `p`aragraphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of your `isDataFilled`:

```
return isEmailCorrect(document.forms["f1"]["email"].value);
return check_word_length(document.forms['f1']['message'].value, 20);
```

The `return` keyword immediately exits the current function; so the second `return` in that code will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

When you `return` a value in a function, it ends that function. So what is after that will not be called. So in this part:

```
return isEmailCorrect(document.forms["f1"]["email"].value);
return check_word_length(document.forms['f1']['message'].value, 20);
```

... the function will stops after `isEmailCorrect` call.

Plus, stop copy/paste codes from web and start try your own codes to know what you're doing.

Comment: This is my own effort dear helper

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is being caused by the fact that isDataFilled returns whatever isEmailCorrect() returns. Execution in the function stops there, so it never calls the last function